# Is it possible to POST a new node to the Jenkins API with curl?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm attempting to automate the process of new Jenkins slaves joining a master, by only performing operations from the new slave. I know I can run a command like the following on new slaves:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://<jenkinsURL>/computer/<myNewNode>/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <secret> -workDir <dir>
```

However in order to run this on a slave, it needs to have already been created on the master otherwise the `http://<jenkinsURL>/computer/<myNewNode>` path will not exist.

To get around this, I'm wondering if it's possible to POST a new node to the Jenkins API. That way I can include it as part of my automated set up of a new Jenkins slave, and simply POST first before downloading and running the agent.jar. I'm attempting to curl it with the following config.xml as the data:

```
<slave>
  <name>myNewNode</name>
  <description>This is my new node</description>
  <remoteFS>/home/jenkins</remoteFS>
  <numExecutors>1</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/>
  <launcher class="hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher">
    <workDirSettings>
      <disabled>false</disabled>
      <internalDir>remoting</internalDir>
      <failIfWorkDirIsMissing>false</failIfWorkDirIsMissing>
    </workDirSettings>
  </launcher>
  <label>label1</label>
  <nodeProperties/>
</slave>
```

but it is not working. It keeps returning an error saying the JENKINS CRUMB is invalid. According to the page here (https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003896171-Creating-node-with-the-REST-API) it is possible to POST an XML node. Does anyone know how, or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The CRUMB issue is probably the result of [CSRF protection](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077), introduced in 2.96. Workaround in [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct. I got it to work with the crumb on an older version of Jenkins, but for the newer version I gave up and used an API token instead, like your link says